# Could shared_from_this be implemented without enable_shared_from_this?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, multiple-inheritance, weak-ptr, enable-shared-from-this

There seem to be some edge-cases when using `enabled_shared_from_this`. For example:

[boost shared_from_this and multiple inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939190/boost-shared-from-this-and-multiple-inheritance)

**Could `shared_from_this` be implemented without using `enable_shared_from_this`?** If so, could it be made as fast?

Comment: Do you mean this as the c++11 replacement/equivalent, for the other boost related question?

Comment: c++11. Is there something different about the c++11 version I should be aware of?

Comment: Not sure. But as is it all just looks a bit to narrow for me compared to the linked Q&A (your question and answer alike). You should try to improve this a bit.

Comment: What else should I say?

Comment: At least I'd give a complete sample for the essentials of the c++11 implementation.

Comment: You mean expand on my answer with sample code?

Comment: Exactly, you got my point.

Comment: Actually I did so :P ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `shared_ptr` is 3 things.  It is a reference counter, a destroyer and an owned resource.

When you `make_shared`, it allocates all 3 at once, then constructs them in that one block.

When you create a `shared_ptr<T>` from a `T*`, you create the reference counter/destroyer separately, and note that the owned resource is the `T*`.

The goal of `shared_from_this` is that we can extract a `shared_ptr<T>` from a `T*` basically (under the assumption it exists).

If all shared pointers where created via `make_shared`, this would be easy (unless you want defined behavior on failure), as the layout is easy.

However, not all shared pointers are created that way.  Sometimes you can create a shared pointer to an object that was not created by any `std` library function, and hence the `T*` is unrelated to the shared pointer reference counting and destruction data.

As there is no *room* in a `T*` or what it points to (in general) to find such constructs, we would have to store it externally, which means global state and thread safety overhead and other pain.  This would be a burden on people who do not need `shared_from_this`, and a performance hit compared to the current state for people who do need it (the mutex, the lookup, etc).

The current design stores a `weak_ptr<T>` in the `enable_shared_from_this<T>`.  This `weak_ptr` is initialized whenever `make_shared` or `shared_ptr<T>` ctor is called.  Now we can create a `shared_ptr<T>` from the `T*` because we have "made room" for it in the class by inheriting from `enable_shared_from_this<T>`.

This is again extremely low cost, and handles the simple cases very well.  We end up with an overhead of one `weak_ptr<T>` over the baseline cost of a `T`.

When you have two different `shared_from_this`, their `weak_ptr<A>` and `weak_ptr<B>` members are unrelated, so it is ambiguous where you want to store the resulting smart pointer (probably both?).  This ambiguity results in the error you see, as it assumes there is exactly one `weak_ptr<?>` member in one unique `shared_from_this<?>` and there is actually two.

[The linked solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14941915/1774667) provides a clever way to extend this.  It writes `enable_shared_from_this_virtual<T>`.

Here instead of storing a `weak_ptr<T>`, we store a `weak_ptr<Q>` where `Q` is a virtual base class of `enable_shared_from_this_virtual<T>`, and does so uniquely in a virtual base class.  It then non-virtually overrides `shared_from_this` and similar methods to provide the same interface as `shared_from_this<T>` does using the "member pointer or child type `shared_ptr` constructor", where you split the reference count/destroyer component from the owned resource component, in a type-safe way.

The overhead here is greater than the basic `shared_from_this`: it has virtual inheritance and forces a virtual destructor, which means the object stores a pointer to a virtual function table, and access to `shared_from_this` is slower as it requires a virtual function table dispatch.

The advantage is it "just works".  There is now one unique `shared_from_this<?>` in the heirarchy, and you can still get type-safe shared pointers to classes `T` that inherit from `shared_from_this<T>`.

Comment: Would be cool to have a version of shared_from_this that assumes the object was allocated using make_shared (and avoids the inheritance). I'd use it!

Comment: @Taylor you'd also have to know what type it was constructed as, now that I think about it -- if we have a pointer-to-Q, and Q is located at offset 47 from the start of the object which is actually a W, finding the shared pointer block from a `Q*` is challenging.  It might be doable with a virtual inheritance table, but I am uncertain.

Comment: I never use virtual inheritance, so I'd love something (obviously not in std) that just made the common case easy.

Comment: Even if you never use `new T` anywhere, you can have `shared_ptr` that were *not* created with `make_shared`, f.ex. those pointing to base subobjects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it could use global hash tables of type

```
unordered_map< T*, weak_ptr<T> >
```

to perform the lookup of a shared pointer from `this`.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
struct MySharedFromThis {
    static unordered_map<T*, weak_ptr<T> > map;

    static std::shared_ptr<T> Find(T* p) {
        auto iter = map.find(p);

        if(iter == map.end())
            return nullptr;

        auto shared = iter->second.lock();
        if(shared == nullptr)
            throw bad_weak_ptr();

        return shared;
    }
};
```

---

```
template<class T>
unordered_map<T*, weak_ptr<T> > MySharedFromThis<T>::map;

template<class T>
struct MyDeleter {
    void operator()(T * p) {
        std::cout << "deleter called" << std::endl;
        auto& map = MySharedFromThis<T>::map;

        auto iter = map.find(p);
        assert(iter != map.end());
        map.erase(iter);
        delete p;
    }
};

template<class T>
shared_ptr<T> MyMakeShared() {
    auto p = shared_ptr<T>(new T, MyDeleter<T>());
    MySharedFromThis<T>::map[p.get()] = p;
    return p;
}

struct Test {
    shared_ptr<Test> GetShared() { return MySharedFromThis<Test>::Find(this); }
};

int main() {
    auto p = MyMakeShared<Test>();

    assert(p);
    assert(p->GetShared() == p);
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5134f228ed43fc5f)

However, the map has to be updated whenever a shared_ptr is constructed from a T*, and before the deleter is called, costing time. Also, to be thread safe, a mutex would have to guard access to the map, serializing allocations of the same type between threads. So this implementation would not perform as well as `enable_shared_from_this`.

**Update:**

Improving on this using the same pointer tricks used by make_shared, here is an implementation which should be just as fast as shared_from_this.

```
template<class T>
struct Holder {
    weak_ptr<T> weak;
    T value;
};

template<class T>
Holder<T>* GetHolder(T* p) {

    // Scary!
    return reinterpret_cast< Holder<T>* >(reinterpret_cast<char*>(p) - sizeof(weak_ptr<T>));

}

template<class T>
struct MyDeleter
{
    void operator()(T * p)
    {
        delete GetHolder(p);
    }
};

template<class T>
shared_ptr<T> MyMakeShared() {
    auto holder = new Holder<T>;
    auto p = shared_ptr<T>(&(holder->value), MyDeleter<T>());
    holder->weak = p;
    return p;
}

template<class T>
shared_ptr<T> MySharedFromThis(T* self) {
    return GetHolder(self)->weak.lock();
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d58e3545281997da)

Comment: Because... what? You compared one thing to... `void()`. _"so this implementation would not perform as well"._ I'm happy you had an insight, but if you want to usefully share this insight (and get appreciation for that, no doubt) it's a good idea to _actually_ exposition it. (_Otherwise it's like handing out your ungroomed back-of-napkin notes to a book editor and say "you can publish this"_)

Comment: Right, because stack overflow is somehow equivalent in formality to publishing a book. LOL! The longer answer above echoes what I said ("a performance hit compared to the current state for people who do need it (the mutex, the lookup, etc)."). The word exposition is a noun, not a verb. I'm interested in information, not points.

Comment: Re: "formality" that's not what I meant. I pointed out that your reasoning here is incomplete. As such it is both not useful (people can not follow your reasoning to gain your insight) and unverifiable. (Thanks for correcting my English)

Comment: @sehe Ok, I added a demo, so now it is verifiable.

Comment: @sehe, also, what is incomplete about my reasoning? How hard is it to understand that accessing a global hash table every time you create or delete an object is going to cause overhead?

Comment: @Taylor Well, is your live demo that big you can't provide the code sample inline?

Comment: @Taylor You read my mind! (I'll abandon the explanation I was trying to cram into a comment. English not being my native language this takes a fair amount of time). The assumption makes this post not self-contained. It's not informative (since obvious) to people who already knew. As given, it appears to be no more than a corollary to the subject post, that somehow got detached from it.

Comment: The assumption being that the reader is somewhat familiar with how enable_shared_from_this works?